# Ultra lightweight video codec

Tags: video

### Specifying Problem

I want to stream my desktop to another computer over 1Gbps Ethernet with following requirments

- Resolution: 1920 x 1080
- FPS: 60
- Input Data: raw 24bit true color (3Gbps)
- Max Output Bitrate: 800Mbps
- Latency: < 50ms (Network latency is less than 1ms)
- CPU: Use less than 20% of [Intel Core2 Quad Q9300](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel%20Core2%20Quad%20Q9300)

suppose that I'm playing a game over the stream (which I'm not) so the frame rate and latency is the most critical issue.

### Question

I'm looking for a lightweight codec that can compress raw data with 10x to 20x speed to real time. (I dont care about bitrate). what codec may suit best for this application?

### Tested Software

- [RDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol): use less than 40Mbps in highest quality and there is no option to set frame rate to 60FPS.
- [TightVNC](https://www.tightvnc.com/): TightVNC allow for specifing quality and encoding algorithm. using `"raw tight"` as `encoding` parameter with AVB 80Mbps  60FPS reached on a 4GHz [Intel Core i7-6700K](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel%20Core%20i7-6700K%20%40%204.00GHz&id=2565) but on lower end machine some serious lag start to apear. using `raw` encoder, lag disappeared but the required bandwidth gets over 3Gbps so the fps is limited and some frame are teared
- [GamingAnywhere](http://gaminganywhere.org/): this software use H264 to encode raw data and send over but encoder prevent from reaching 60FPS (used bandwidth is < 60Mbps)

### Tested Encoders

- H264: run at 1.33x (1x mean 60FPS)
- MJPEG: run at 0.33x
- PNG: PNG is more computational complex than MJPEG so i dont test it.

Comment: Depending on your graphics card you might be able to use Nvidia Game Streaming ( part of the GeForce Experience software) to stream your system. Pretty sure it can work at 60fps, and because it directly encodes using the hardware on your graphics card the stream is very low latency. There are some tweaks to make it work as a remote desktop session by adding `mstsc.exe` to its program list, but I think it will only work on a Pro edition of Windows. Using the hardware video encoder blocks to record and stream is going to produce the lowest latency.

Comment: The latest ffmpeg can support hardware video encoding and I believe can capture the current display and can, I believe, also stream across the network. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro Most modern graphics cards have both hardware video encoding and decoding.